# Session problem in IE

Tags: php

I have written two functions `setSes()` and `getSes()` and here I have written `session_start()`.Its wroking for all browser except IE.

```
function setSes(){
 $res=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from table1 limit 1"));//data from DB
 $_SESSION['ses1']=$res['name'];//Its not working .... $res['name']='Raj'
 $_SESSION['ses1']="priyabrata";//Its working
}

function getSes(){
 session_start();
 print"<pre>";
 print_r($_SESSION);
}
```

please get some ideas

Comment: probably your problem has to do with cache.

Comment: your 1st problem is mysql query is not pulling data

Comment: He wrote that only IE refuses to work properly. What does a browser have to do with the RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Session writes a cookie, called `PHPSESSID` or something like that. You can change the name in php.ini or with special php functions.

Anyway, the browser must accept cookies for sessions to work. IE (earlier versions, maybe even later) has an enforced security policy, which makes it hard to transmit cookies.

I suggest you read [this](http://genotrance.wordpress.com/2006/11/23/session-cookies-rejected-by-internet-explorer/) article, which has a comprehensive study of this exact problem, and solutions.

I've been having this problem a lot with IE. If server timestamp was incorrect, or other server settings looked "fishy" to the cookie filter, the cookie was not accepted. Of course most of these security settings can be changed and turned off in IE, but it would have to be done on the client side, which isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the session first Before you set the variables.  You may be doing this but in the code you linked you don't show what order getSes() or setSes() is called and you appear to be editing it on the fly so I can't really keep up.

Read up on the start session function here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code implies that you use `getSes()` to get some value from your session, and `setSes()` if you want to set it. Now logically, you would set a value before you can get it, right?

But with this code, you would not have called `session_start()` while setting your var.
Call `session_start()` first thing in your script, and it might go over better....

Comment: @Nanne--- We have included a css file of fancybox css and there is some line like this at the end of fancybox css file(jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.css)".fancybox-ie #fancybox-bg-n { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='fancybox/fancy_shadow_n.png', sizingMethod='scale'); }".After remove of those line I found the session is working.But I did not get the solution,will any one explain me?

Comment: Hmm. I really have no clue. Those two things should be completely separate (remember that css is parsed at the client-side of things, while your session (php) code is parsed before it goes to the client). Maybe you should make a really small example that also has this behaviour (a small-as-possible css file that does 'block' your sessions, and one that does not, and a complete php file that goes with it..). It does sound quite obscure, sorry I can't help more :)